# How to keep Datetime index? ValueWarning: An unsupported index was provided and will be ignored when e.g. forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, indexing, valueerror

I have a dataframe which gets split in train and test data using this code:

```
train = df.iloc[:1000]
test = df.iloc[1000:]
```

I now want to use ARIMA to forecast into the future:

```
model = ARIMA(train['IdCount'],order=(1,1,0))
results = model.fit()
```

To get the predicted values I used this code:

```
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)-1
predictions = results.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False, typ='levels').rename('ARIMA(1,1,0) Predictions')
```

Unfortunately I got this ValueWarning:

```
ValueWarning: No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start`.
```

And predictions does not have the datetime index anymore but integer values as index.

For plotting the predictions together with test data I used this code:

```
test['IdCount'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,8))
predictions.plot(legend=True)
```

And then get this error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -35838.3 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

How could I keep the datetime index for the predictions instead of the integer values? Or should I create this index synthetically? Is there a reason why this index is not supported?

Comment: You train a model with the data `train` and get the model `results`. And than, you want to predict the data starting at an index larger than `len(train)`. That can't work. The data of the model is only `len(train)` long. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, the dataframe `df` for the whole data has a `df(len)` of 1157. So, I do not think that is the reason.

Comment: To get rid of ValueWarning, you need to put your dates as `df.index`